# Get variable value from XML to JavaScript. Pure way

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, variables

I have XML:

```
<point>
    ...
    <longitude>34.123123</longitude>
</point>
<point>
    ...
    <longitude>11.12534534</longitude>
</point>
<point>
    ...
    <longitude>32.567653</longitude>
</point>
<point>
    ...
    <longitude>33.345345</longitude>
</point>
...
```

Task:

get values of `<longitude>` in javascript (in variable).

Which is purest way?

It is possible to do it without XSLT (without making dummy elements)?

---

**Update:**

I have very badly explained.

XML it is dynamically formed on a server, then in the same place passes XSLT and it turns out HTML which is sent in a browser.

Probably in HTML it is necessary to make a fictitious element in which to write down value of a longitude, then to read out its value in javascript from an element on page.

How it is possible to make differently?

Comment: Are you using any javascript frameworks or is that not an option here?

Comment: @Nick Craver, just pure javascript.

Comment: Is the XML in a string or a separate file?

Answer (score 3):

How about jQuery?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "relative/path/to/yourfile.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) {
     $(xml).find('point').each(function(){
       var longitude = $(this).find('longitude').text()

       // doing something with your longitude variable
     });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an [XML parser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) assuming you have a string. If it's a file, AJAX should do the parsing heavy-lifting for you. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jr5ga/

```
/**
 * Parse XML from string
 * Abstract away browser differences
 */
​function parseXML(text) {
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
    }
    else { // Internet Explorer
        doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        doc.async="false";
        doc.loadXML(text);
    }
    return doc;
}
```

To get the longitude values from this XML document, you can use the `getElementsByTagName` function. Once all longitude nodes are selected, loop through them and to get the text content in each node, call `childNodes[0]` since it only has 1 child - the text node, and call `nodeValue` on the text node to get the value as a string.

```
var xml = parseXML(string);

var longitudes = xml.getElementsByTagName("longitude");
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < longitudes.length; i++) {
    // add longitude value to "result" array
    result.push(longitudes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: @Anurag, I so understand that the offered variant does not approach, because I have badly explained a problem. For realisation of your decision the line is necessary, and it at me is not present (it it is necessary to get from a server). Your reception very much was pleasant to me, I will remember it and I will apply in the future for XML parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Making an AJAX call to the XML source can help you. But it depends on where you store the xml document.

Check out the following link, especially the XMLHttpRequest part:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp